# Load json from url as a String or String array

Tags: python, json

I try to load a json from a url as a string or an array of strings.
As for now it seem's I have an array of characters.
When I print the data in the terminal it looks ok.
It is about 250 lines of json. But when I check the array length it is an array of 8500 elements.

```
import urllib2
import json


def main():
    filter_json("52942")

def filter_json(id):
    url = "http://ccmixter.org/api/query?f=json&t=info&ids="+id
    site = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    data = json.loads(site)
    data =  json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': '))

    # this looks good:
    #print data

    # this is 8500 which are characters?
    print len(data)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: if data is a string `len(data)` will give you the amount of chars in the string. that's why it's 8500.
And you are assigning the `data` variable twice

Comment: How can I loop over lines then?

Comment: why would you loop over the lines? the result is a json string.

Comment: Iterate over lines in a json is very imprecise as they could be as long or shot as you want them.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
data = json.loads(site)
```

loads the json data into a list. If you call `len(data)` directly after it, `data` will be a list (or whatever json the API returned), and you'll get the length of the list.

This line:

```
data =  json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': '))
```

turns the list back into a  string, so you'll get the length of the string (which is then 8500 characters long with indents and whitespaces)